# How to search a custom character in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, character-encoding

My current Windows 7 is in English. I have some files transferred from another computer which contains non-english characters.
Look at the picture below

[image]

Now, I want to delete them all. But writing this character in search box doesn't give the desired files.

[image]

How can I delete all the files which includes non-english/non-word characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cihad, PowerShell is probably your best bet here.

I did a little test to find all non-English chars in a folder using the code below

```
Get-ChildItem c:\TurkishFileNames\ | where-object {$_.name -match "[^\x00-\x80]+"}
```

That returns all those non-english file names. You can then pass them to remove-item, but first establish that you are getting the correct names. One wrinkle here is you were talking about 'folder' names, and I tested this with file names.

Still, I believe you can use the same trick. If you  have PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0 installed, you can use -directory to display only folder names when using Get-ChildItem:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\TurkishFolderNames\ -directory
```

The rest is going to be similar. You can download PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0 from Microsoft

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 (WMF 3.0)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855 (WMF 4.0)

Windows 7 came with PowerShell 2.0, if you will stick with that you can still use the old syntax to get directories only:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TurkishFolderNames\ | ? {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $true}
```

You can then proceed with the rest:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TurkishFolderNames\ | ? {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $true} | ? {$_.name -match "[^\x00-\x80]+"}
```

Comment: That's cool. Actually you forgot to say `-r` :) also I needed to write characters one by one like `[\xb1\xc4]`

Comment: Well, I did not mean the examples to be literal. I have no idea how your folder structure looks. If it is hierarchical, then sure, throw -recursive in there.

Answer (score 0):

As taken from my good friend Adam here: [Can't search by dollar amounts that are in filename.](https://superuser.com/a/675122/128359)

You may need to wrap your search in the following way:

`~="searchterm"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't retrieve any results. If you read the comments below on your link, they already commented this method is not working in anyway.

Comment: The method works, however it did not work for that particular user. I have tested it, and it does work. In your case though I'm not sure what the issue would be...

Comment: I'll try to find solution on this. Most probably that character belongs to another language so that makes problem. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to find files with a specific character is [Powershell](http://ss64.com/ps/)

```
dir D:\* -r -include *∓*
```

You can also use [unicode notation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2213/index.htm): `0x2213` is equivalent to `U+2213`

```
$char = [char]0x2213
dir D:\* -r -include *$char*
```

---

Btw. using the Windows search does give me correct result with your special characters!
Are you sure you haven't misconfigured something? ([My config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ6Uj.png))

[image]

Comment: Tried, still gave me no results :( It's probably because of encoding. Is there any way to search explicitly define a character like `U+2213`

Comment: @CihadTurhan and now? :)

Comment: Command line unicode works thanks. I tried Adil's answer already. Well, that's interesting. When I write in search box like yours I can't find that any result. I believe it's because that combination of ∓, ÿ etc represnts other characters like ş,ı,ö so it can't find.

Comment: @CihadTurhan I use `partial matches` and disabled search index. Maybe thats the cause? Can I have your example where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I believe it's a language problem. When I type ÅŸ it finds for example `ayrac.png` but not `sÅŸra.png`. Thanks for your effort. I'll go with command line.